# How to keep multiple views in Sync if I am viewing website on phone, PC, Tablet same time?

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node.js Express app which is basically just a single slider. I want to be able to control the slider from my phone and have it updating on the computer screen in realtime..

At the minute the site opens up on all devices and they can all move the slider but the views aren't updating in realtime..

Comment: You need to add a little bit of code. Please don't expect people to write the full program from the scratch. That said this is something my friend made long time back. You may get some idea from it.
http://athousandnodes.com/article/cross-browser-elements-nodejs

Comment: Well I thought about including the code but theres quite a lot of code and I didn't know how to share it.. I was more asking for general solutions on how this is usually solved.. the answer below told me websockets and long polling..

Comment: The ideal solution I would say for all time synce solution is to use meteor.io instead of express. https://www.meteor.com/

If you want to use express you need to look for socket.io or even better would be express-io. 
http://express-io.org/

Comment: Thankyou for the help, I remember looking at Meteor in the past and also Sails I think it was called.. I am an electronic engineer so web development isn't my strong point. I want a good easy to use system for getting all my various electronics projects online in realtime, meteor looks like it could be it.. you don't know of any others I should check out do you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You could use long polling.**

The "computer screen" app registers a long poll connection with your node.js server.

```
// This example uses JQuery

function longPoll() {
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        // update your view
    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
};
```

The "phone" app sends a GET request to server that passes it through the open long poll connection to the "computer screen" app.

Each time the "computer screen" app receives a reply it will have to open a new long poll connection.

Search for long polling or Comet for more information.

**Another solution would be using websockets. Node.js has several websockets libraries that can be used.**

Using Socket.IO

Server side:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(80);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('connected', true);
  socket.on('onScroll', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Client side:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
  socket.on('connected', function (data) {
    socket.emit('onScroll', { delta: x });
  });
</script>
```

**Here is an example using express and Socket.IO to build a chat service**

http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/real-time-chat-with-nodejs-socketio-and-expressjs--net-31708

Comment: Thankyou so much, see I have used web sockets before but I thought they were just about passing messages to and from the server I didn't know it could be done to refresh the page too.. I am such a newb with web development